# I want to use the mouse enter and mouse leave sub on a control I added through the controls.add function

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I added a control using "Controls.Add()" and I want to use the mouse enter sub on it. I thought that I could use this:

```
Private Sub HealingPotion_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HealingPotion.MouseEnter

End Sub
```

"HealingPotion" is the control added using "Controls.Add()" but it doesnt recognize the variable. Can someone help?

Comment: Use `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` to problematically add or remove event handlers from dynamic (or static) controls. The `Handles` keyword only works for static controls created in the designer.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use it?

Comment: `AddHandler HealingPotion.MouseEnter, addressof (HealingPotion_MouseEnter)`.  You will need to do that at the same place you add the control.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What is "cmd"? And what does "addressof" do? I'm not very experienced.

Comment: "cmd" was a typo on my part. That should be the name of the variable that is holding a reference to the new control (the same thing you used in Controls.Add). `AddressOf` is just the way you get a function reference in VB.NET.  As a whole, the line just tells the control that when it sees the named event, call the referenced function.  If you ever remove the control through code you should call `RemoveHandler` exactly the same way.

Comment: It give me this error: ''HealingPotion_MouseEnter' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.' Also, the control is being added to a form from code from a different form. I have two forms: AdventureForm and Inventory; I have this code on the AdventureForm: 'My.Forms.Inventory.Itemtab.Controls.Add(HealingPotion)'. So that might affect it.

Comment: Did you delete the `HealingPotion_MouseEnter` sub that you gave in your example?  You still need to have that there (without the `Handles` clause).  Thats the code that it will run on mouse enter.

Comment: I tried to put it in, but it still didnt recognize it. Is it because it was added to a separate form?

Comment: Probably. As written it will look for that sub in the same class that the the call to `AddHandler` is in.  If you want the sub to be on a different form reference you will need to prefix the `addressof` call with the form reference, like `addressof SomeOtherForm.NameOfFunctionToCall`.  The sub will also have to be defined as `Public Sub` instead of `Private` or `Protected`.

Comment: Like this? 'AddHandler HealingPotion.MouseEnter, AddressOf Inventory.HealingPotion_MouseEnter,

Comment: That seems like it should be correct, but I can't say for sure because I don't have access to all your code.  Make sure that `HealingPotion_MouseEnter` is declared like `Public Sub HealingPotion_MouseEnter(sender as object, e as EventArgs)`

Comment: It gave me this error on the Sub: 'Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.'

Comment: You need to get rid of the `Handles` clause on the sub.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Bradley!!!